# How do I fill two (or more) numpy arrays from a single iterable of tuples?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

The actual problem I have is that I want to store a long sorted list of `(float, str)` tuples in RAM. A plain list doesn't fit in my 4Gb RAM, so I thought I could use two `numpy.ndarray`s.

The source of the data is an iterable of 2-tuples. `numpy` has a `fromiter` function, but how can I use it? The number of items in the iterable is unknown. I can't consume it to a list first due to memory limitations. I thought of `itertools.tee`, but it seems to add a lot of memory overhead here.

What I guess I could do is consume the iterator in chunks and add those to the arrays. Then my question is, how to do that efficiently? Should I maybe make 2 2D arrays and add rows to them? (Then later I'd need to convert them to 1D).

Or maybe there's a better approach? Everything I really need is to search through an array of strings by the value of the corresponding number in logarithmic time (that's why I want to sort by the value of float) and to keep it as compact as possible.

P.S. The iterable is not sorted.

Comment: Would using `np.fromiter` to build a single array with two columns suffice?

Comment: @unutbu ...I'm not sure why I haven't considered that :) Sounds like a great idea. Then I just sort it along the longer axis and keep it that way, right? You could post it as an answer, I suppose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps build a single, structured array using `np.fromiter`:

```
import numpy as np


def gendata():
    # You, of course, have a different gendata...
    for i in xrange(N):
        yield (np.random.random(), str(i))

N = 100

arr = np.fromiter(gendata(), dtype='<f8,|S20')
```

Sorting it by the first column, using the second for tie-breakers will take O(N log N) time:

```
arr.sort(order=['f0','f1'])
```

Finding the row by the value in the first column can be done with `searchsorted` in O(log N) time:

```
# Some pseudo-random value in arr['f0']
val = arr['f0'][10]
print(arr[10])
# (0.049875262239617246, '46')

idx = arr['f0'].searchsorted(val)
print(arr[idx])
# (0.049875262239617246, '46')
```

---

You've asked many important questions in the comments; let me attempt to answer them here:

- The basic dtypes are explained in the [numpybook](http://web.archive.org/web/20130405085237/http://www.tramy.us/). There may be one or
  two extra dtypes (like `float16` which have been added since that
  book was written, but the basics are all explained there.)

  Perhaps a more thorough discussion is in the [online documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html). Which is a good supplement to the examples you mentioned [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html).
- Dtypes can be used to define structured arrays with column names, or
  with default column names. `'f0'`, `'f1'`, etc. are default column
  names. Since I defined the dtype as `'<f8,|S20'` I failed to provide
  column names, so NumPy named the first column `'f0'`, and the second
  `'f1'`. If we had used

  ```
  dtype='[('fval','<f8'), ('text','|S20')]
  ```

  then the structured array `arr` would have column names `'fval'` and
  `'text'`.
- Unfortunately, the dtype has to be fixed at the time `np.fromiter` is called. You
  could conceivably iterate through `gendata` once to discover the
  maximum length of the strings, build your dtype and then call
  `np.fromiter` (and iterate through `gendata` a second time), but
  that's rather burdensome. It is of course better if you know in
  advance the maximum size of the strings. (`|S20` defines the string
  field as having a fixed length of 20 bytes.)
- NumPy arrays place data of a
  pre-defined size in arrays of a fixed size. Think of the array (even multidimensional ones) as a contiguous block of one-dimensional memory. (That's an oversimplification -- there are non-contiguous arrays -- but will help your imagination for the following.) NumPy derives much of its speed by taking advantage of the fixed sizes (set by the `dtype`) to quickly compute the offsets needed to access elements in the array. If the strings had variable sizes, then it
  would be hard for NumPy to find the right offsets. By hard, I mean
  NumPy would need an index or somehow be redesigned. NumPy is simply not
  built this way.
- NumPy does have an `object` dtype which allows you to place a 4-byte
  pointer to any Python object you desire. This way, you can have NumPy
  arrays with arbitrary Python data. Unfortunately, the `np.fromiter`
  function does not allow you to create arrays of dtype `object`. I'm not sure why there is this restriction...
- Note that `np.fromiter` has better performance when the `count` is
  specified. By knowing the `count` (the number of rows) and the
  `dtype` (and thus the size of each row) NumPy can pre-allocate
  exactly enough memory for the resultant array. If you do not specify
  the `count`, then NumPy will make a guess for the initial size of the
  array, and if too small, it will try to resize the array. If the
  original block of memory can be extended you are in luck. But if
  NumPy has to allocate an entirely new hunk of memory then all the old
  data will have to be copied to the new location, which will slow down
  the performance significantly.

Comment: Wow, there's a lot of new stuff for me here, e.g. the `fX` indexing syntax, but mainly the dtype you used. Firstly, are possible dtypes documented? I found [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html) but I'd use some explanation rather than just examples. Does the size have to be fixed (I guess so if it's a plain array)? Because in an ideal world I neither want it to have upper limit, nor do I want short strings to take extra space. Can I get something like that?

Comment: If you do not specify `count`, will `np.fromiter` not have to first build a list from the iterator, and then convert it to an array?

Comment: @Jaime: If you do not specify `count`, then `np.fromiter` will have to resize the numpy array when the data outgrows the pre-allocated output array. If you have enough contiguous memory, it will not have to copy data when it resizes, and at no point is a Python list used.

Comment: Thanks again. From the book it seems that the dtype of `object_` makes only a reference to the object to be stored in the array. If it's true, can I use that?

Comment: This goes into an area of NumPy which I am shady about. From what I can understand of the C source code, a call to `PyDataType_REFCHK(dtype)` fails when the `dtype` (or part of it) is of type `object`. My understanding of `C` is not strong, so I'm going to have to just refer you to [the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L3467).

Comment: Thanks again for all your help; now my problem is that `arr['f0'].searchsorted(val)` seems to be embarrassingly slow as compared to `searchsorted` on a separate array of floats. Is there any obvious reason&solution or should I ask a separate question?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is so much slower, though I can reproduce the problem. If you have enough memory to make a copy `x = arr['f0'].copy()` then `x.searchsorted(val)` will be faster. Otherwise, it's back to the drawing board -- we will need to find another way to build 2 separate arrays out of `gendata()`.

Comment: Of course, I would prefer to avoid the duplication: memory is the main reason I started using `numpy` here; the performance of `bisect` on a list is not much worse than `numpy.searchsorted()` on a float array. I'll stick to copying as a workaround for now. Of course if you have another idea for building 2 arrays, you are welcome to post another answer :) I will also consider rewriting `gendata`, I actually just thought of a way to "unzip" its output. But anyway, do you think this performance question is worth a question or maybe a ticket?

Comment: I think the searchsorted peformance issue is definitely worth a Stackoverflow question. If you do not get a satisfactory answer, you might also try posting to the [NumPy-discussion mailing list](http://www.scipy.org/Mailing_Lists). You'll get a faster preliminary response there than from filing a ticket. The mailing list will also bring your question to the attention of the developers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to build `N` separate arrays out of a generator of `N`-tuples:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as IT


def gendata():
    # You, of course, have a different gendata...
    N = 100
    for i in xrange(N):
        yield (np.random.random(), str(i))


def fromiter(iterable, dtype, chunksize=7):
    chunk = np.fromiter(IT.islice(iterable, chunksize), dtype=dtype)
    result = [chunk[name].copy() for name in chunk.dtype.names]
    size = len(chunk)
    while True:
        chunk = np.fromiter(IT.islice(iterable, chunksize), dtype=dtype)
        N = len(chunk)
        if N == 0:
            break
        newsize = size + N
        for arr, name in zip(result, chunk.dtype.names):
            col = chunk[name]
            arr.resize(newsize, refcheck=0)
            arr[size:] = col
        size = newsize
    return result

x, y = fromiter(gendata(), '<f8,|S20')

order = np.argsort(x)
x = x[order]
y = y[order]

# Some pseudo-random value in x
N = 10
val = x[N]
print(x[N], y[N])
# (0.049875262239617246, '46')

idx = x.searchsorted(val)
print(x[idx], y[idx])
# (0.049875262239617246, '46')
```

The `fromiter` function above reads the iterable in chunks (of size `chunksize`). It calls the NumPy array method `resize` to extend the resultant arrays as necessary.

I used a small default `chunksize` since I was testing this code on small data. You, of course, will want to either change the default chunksize or pass a `chunksize` parameter with a larger value.

Comment: Yeah, reading in chunks was on my mind, too, thanks for the great example. Can't we pass `chunksize` to `np.fromiter` here to speed it up?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a way. If we use `count=chunksize`, the call to `np.fromiter` may fail if the iterable contains less than `chunksize` items. And if we try to catch that in a `try..except` block, then we will lose data since the iterable is only good for one pass.